# What is this regex doing?

Tags: regex, perl

```
/^([a-z]:)?\//i
```

I don't quite understand what the `?` in this regex if I had to explain it from what I understood:

Match begin "Group1 is a to z and :" outside `?` (which I don't get what its doing) `\/` which makes it match `/` and option `/i` "case insensitive".

I realize that this will return 0 or 1 not quiet sure why because of the `?`

Is this to match directory path or something ?

If I test it:

`$var = 'test'` would get 0 while `$var ='/test';` would get 1 but `$var = 'test/'` gets 0

So anything that begins with `/` will get 1 and anything else 0.

Can someone explain this regex in elementary terms to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?` will match one or none of the preceding pattern.

```
?      Match 1 or 0 times
```

See also: [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Explanation:

```
/.../i   # case insensitive

^(...)   # match at the beginning of the string

[a-z]:   # one character between 'a' and 'z' followed by a colon

(...)?   # zero or one time of the group, enclosed in ()
```

So in english: Match anything which begins with a `/` (slash) or some letter followed by a colon followed by a `/`. This looks like it matches pathnames across unix and windows, e.g.
it would match:

```
/home/user
```

and

```
C:/Applications
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks again for the long explanation that makes it clear now.

Answer (score 9):

See [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/YAPE::Regex::Explain):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(qr/^([a-z]:)?\//i)->explain;
```

```
The regular expression:

(?i-msx:^([a-z]:)?/)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?i-msx:                 group, but do not capture (case-insensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you're using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Using regexes to decode regexes... that'll take some getting used to.

Answer (score 8):

It matches a lower- or upper case letter (`[a-z]` with the `i` modifier) positioned at the start of the input string (`^`) followed by a colon (`:`) all optionally (`?`), followed by a forward slash `\/`.

In short:

```
^          # match the beginning of the input
(          # start capture group 1
  [a-z]    #   match any character from the set {'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z'} (with the i-modifier!)
  :        #   match the character ':'
)?         # end capture group 1 and match it once or none at all
\/         # match the character '/'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is looking for a "rooted" path. It will successfully match any string that either starts with a forward slash (/test), or a drive letter followed by a colon, followed by a forward slash (c:/test).

Comment: And probably badly, because if your path starts with a letter and a colon, you're likely going to have backslashes instead of slashes.

Comment: thanks that explains what i was missing  it was actually made for win and linux.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the question mark makes something optional. It applies to the part in parentheses, which is a letter followed by a colon.

Things that will match:

```
C:/
a:/
/
```

(That last item above is why the ? is there)

Things that will not match:

```
C:
a:
ab:/
a/
```